# cocoa touch NSDateFormatter and epoch date

Tags: cocoa-touch, date, nsdateformatter

I have a string that is (I think) an epoch date.  Here is the example string:

```
1372620996
```

Heres part of the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *offerDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1372620996"];
```

This returns a null date, and I'm pretty sure my problem is because I haven't set a dateStyle on my NSDateFormatter.  However, I'm not sure what dateStyle to use for an epoch date.

Comment: To use an NSDateFormatter you have to provide it with a [format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).  Otherwise it doesn't know what to look for.  Presumably the correct format would be `@"AAAAAAAAAA"`, but it's much easier to use the `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` function of NSDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually simpler than that to convert to an NSDate;

```
NSString *dateStr = @"1372620996";
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[dateStr doubleValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", date);

> 2013-06-30 19:36:36 +0000
```