# Converting an InternetDateTimeString in a NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

That's my code

```
[NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:internetTime formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC3339];
```

In the terminal I receive this message

> Could not parse RFC822 date: "1370835005000" Possible invalid format.
> Could not parse RFC3339 date: "1370835005000" Possible invalid format.

Which format I must use to correctly convert this internet data time in a NSDate format?

Comment: `dateFromInternetDateTimeString` is not an iOS function, but is presumably a 3rd-party category function.  I'd suggest you read the source (which you must have somewhere) to see what it does.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394555/cocoa-touch-nsdateformatter-and-epoch-date/17394769#17394769

Comment: If you remove the last 3 digits, you'll get the total number of seconds since 1970?

Comment: what exactly is InternetDateTimeString? is it a unix timestamp?

Comment: The strings are the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 1000 to get the seconds, convert it to double and create the date:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[internetTime doubleValue]/1000.0];
```

Comment: Actually as the given timestamp appears to be in milliseconds (a la Java), it should be `NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[internetTime doubleValue]/1000.0];`